# R filtering table and inserting information

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, merge

I currently have following table structure

**Table1**

```
id  a
11  4
11  3
22  1
22  3
22  5
33  2
33  1
44  6
44  8
66  5
66  7
77  6
```

**Table2**

```
id  score 
11  12
33  22
44  20
```

I want to delete every row from Table1, that does not contain any of the id in Table2$id. `unique(Table2$id)` should generate such an unique id list. Further, I need to write the *score* from Table2 into each corresponding id of Table1. The desired dataframe would be:

**Result**

```
id  a score 
11  4 12
11  3 12
33  2 22
33  1 22
44  6 20
44  8 20
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
merge(Table2, Table1, by = "id")
```

should do it.